# Handling an IAsyncOperation<StorageFile^>^ object in C++/CX

Tags: file, uwp, c++-cx

I want to create a file in the local folder, so I have written the following code:

```
IAsyncOperation<StorageFile^>^ fileTask = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->CreateFileAsync("example.dat");
```

But how should I handle the fileTask?
I have tried to call the `GetResults`-method, but then I get following exception:

```
Ausnahme ausgelöst bei 0x00007FFD211C7788 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (Parameter: 0x000000008000000E, 0x0000000000000040, 0x000000C00EBFC470).
Ausnahme ausgelöst bei 0x00007FFD211C7788 in Test.exe: Microsoft C++-Ausnahme: Platform::COMException ^ bei Speicherort 0x000000C00EBFC730. HRESULT:0x8000000E Eine Methode wurde zu einem unerwarteten Zeitpunkt aufgerufen.
WinRT-Informationen: Eine Methode wurde zu einem unerwarteten Zeitpunkt aufgerufen.
```

---

Next I have tried to use `create_task`:

```
create_task(Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->CreateFileAsync("example.dat")).then([this](StorageFile^ file)
{
    // irrelevant
});
```

Exception:

```
Ausnahme ausgelöst bei 0x00007FFD211C7788 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (Parameter: 0x00000000800700B7, 0x0000000000000048, 0x000000A936DFB230).
Ausnahme ausgelöst bei 0x00007FFD211C7788 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0xE06D7363: Microsoft C++ Exception (Parameter: 0xCCCCCCCC19930520, 0x000000A936DFB830, 0x00007FFD01398AD0, 0x00007FFD012C0000).
```

*Sorry for the language*

How could I solve this Problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Next I have tried to use create_task...

You are in the correct direction. It is recommended to use [task class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh750113.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for async operation.

But the file `example.dat` is probably already there when you call the `GetResults`. Thus you won't be able to use `create_task(Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->CreateFileAsync("example.dat")).then([this](StorageFile^ file)` to create the file again.

To fix the problem, just modify the codes like below:

```
#include <ppltasks.h>
create_task(Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->CreateFileAsync("example.dat", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting)).then([this](StorageFile^ file)
{

});
```

Added `CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting` so that everytime the new file will replace the old file. And don't forget to include the `ppltask.h`.